# Admob's onDismissScreen() event never fired when return to application after banner is clicked

Tags: android, admob, banner

I have issue with Admob (6.4.1) banner for Android. When I click on a banner, web browser opens. If I return to my application with home button, browser opens and `onDismissScreen()` is not fired. When I go back to my application with back button, banner stops to show and `loadAd called while an interstitial or landing page is displayed, so aborting` appear in log. I use just xml definition of `AdView` with `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"`. I use Ad House with client banners, `MinSDK = 8` and `targetSDK = 17`.

Log:

```
11-06 15:08:30.034: I/Ads(275): Received ad url: <url: ... the Ad."
11-06 15:08:30.034: I/Ads(275): Request scenario: Online server request.
11-06 15:08:30.044: W/webcore(275): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
11-06 15:08:30.804: W/webcore(275): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
11-06 15:08:31.094: D/webviewglue(275): nativeDestroy view: 0x437cb0
11-06 15:08:31.094: I/Ads(275): onReceiveAd()
11-06 15:08:31.154: D/webviewglue(275): nativeDestroy view: 0x51aaa0
11-06 15:08:36.865: I/Ads(275): onPresentScreen()
11-06 15:08:36.915: I/Ads(275): onLeaveApplication()
11-06 15:08:36.955: I/Ads(275): onPresentScreen()
11-06 15:08:36.975: I/Ads(275): onLeaveApplication()
11-06 15:08:43.395: D/dalvikvm(275): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11279 objects / 983360 bytes in 159ms
```